# <Error>: CGImageSourceGetType image source parameter is nil\n - iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, uiwebview

I'm seeing this in the Debugger Console:

```
<Error>: CGImageSourceGetType image source parameter is nil\n
```

I think it may be related to the UIWebView used by the Mobclix ad library.

I didn't observe any adverse behavior in my app, but I may be missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen this same message when working with HTML5  tags in a UIWebView.  It appears to be triggered by fill() calls when filling a shape with color.  I wasn't able to isolate the problem, although replacing hex colors in fillStyle() stopped the errors from appearing in my case.

```
context.fillStyle = '#666'; //causes errors
context.fillStyle = 'rgb(100,100,100)'; //no errors
context.fill(); //error appeared when this statement was executed
```

My guess on the source of this issue is an obscure bug in Safari's usage of CoreGraphics to render the  related JavaScript API calls.